# pandas: create rows of sentences (with identifier) from text

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, spacy

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
textID1, text1, othermetadata1
textID2, text2, othermetadata2
textID3, text3, othermetadata3
```

I would like to break the texts into sentences in a new data frame that would look like this:

```
textID1-001, sentence1 (of text1), othermetadata1
textID1-002, sentence2 (of text1), othermetadata1
textID2-001, sentence1 (of text2), othermetadata2
```

I know how to break texts into sentences using either the NLTK or spaCy, e.g.:

```py
sentences = [ sent_tokenize(text) for text in texts ]
```

But pandas continues to confound me: how do I take the output and pack it back into a data frame? Moreover, how do I add numbers either to an extant column or create a new column that restarts numbering with each text -- my assumption being that I could merge the **textID** and **sentenceID** columns afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your list of sentences for a given row, you can break them into separate rows using [explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). Exploding the rows maintains the index of the original DF and using [cumcount()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), you can generate consecutive IDs for your original rows.

Here I am assuming your text ID column is called "text_id" and sentences column is called "sentences".

```
df = df.explode(['sentences']).reset_index().rename(columns={'index' : 'row_id'})
df['row_id'] = df.groupby('row_id').cumcount()
```

If you want to combine your text ID column with the row_id, you can just use the following:

```
df['text_id'] = df['text_id'] + "-" + df["row_id"]
```

Complete solution for the above:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

df = pd.DataFrame([["textID1", "text1 sentence1. text1 sentence2", "othermetadata1"],
["textID2", "text2 sentence1", "othermetadata2"],
["textID3", "text3 sentence1. text3 sentence2. text3 sentence3", "othermetadata3"]], columns=["text_id", "text", "metadata"])

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(sent_tokenize)
df = df.explode("text").reset_index().rename(columns={'index' : 'row_id'})
df['row_id'] = df.groupby('row_id').cumcount()
df['text_id'] = df['text_id'] + "-" + df["row_id"].astype('str')

df = df.drop(columns=['row_id'])
df
```

```
     text_id              text        metadata
0  textID1-0  text1 sentence1.  othermetadata1
1  textID1-1   text1 sentence2  othermetadata1
2  textID2-0   text2 sentence1  othermetadata2
3  textID3-0  text3 sentence1.  othermetadata3
4  textID3-1  text3 sentence2.  othermetadata3
5  textID3-2   text3 sentence3  othermetadata3
```

Comment: I still struggle with pandas' logic: normally I would do this in a `for` loop, but is there a pandas-native way to run the `sent_tokenize`? Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: If your sentences are clean and are separated by a character like ".", the fastest way to do this in Pandas would be to use a vectorized operation like `df['text'].str.split('.')`.
If you really need to use a function to do your splitting, you can use `df['text'].apply(sent_tokenize)`

Comment: NLTK's `sent_tokenize` returns the most sentences out of a somewhat mixed bag of texts. I'm not sure if I follow the logic: your code in the comment suggests that a column `['sentences']` is added to the dataframe? My assumption is that I would (somehow!) get a list of sentences out of the `['text']` column. I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: You could directly explode the output of the `df/series.apply(sent_tokenize)` but if you want to duplicate the metadata and other rows, I think you may have to assign the output of the sent_tokenize to a column of the DF first. I have updated my answer with a complete solution above. Does that help?

Comment: Doh! Sorry for my misunderstanding, and thank you for the expanded version. I can see where I was confused and understand a bit better how to work with pandas!

Comment: Fascinating, when I run the toy corpus you provided above, everything works. When I run my actual corpus, things break at the `groupby` line: `KeyError: 'row_id'`.

Comment: Have you done the step where you rename your `index` column to `'row_id'`?
`df.rename(columns={'index' : 'row_id'})`

Comment: Doesn't that happen in `df = df.explode("text").reset_index().rename(columns={'index' : 'row_id'})`?

Comment: I was just wondering if you had that line in your actual code. Strange that `groupby` isn't detecting the `row_id` column. Have you confirmed that the `row_id` column is indeed present by running `df.columns` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254664/discussion-between-john-laudun-and-zee).